# Unable to differentiate between note and message in Odoo 12

Tags: notifications, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12, quotations

When I log any note (after clicking log note link) inside `sale-> quotations or CRM -> activity`

After entering any note when I check in notification section is doesn't show 'Note By ...' label in Odoo 12, in Odoo 11 it works fine.

I debugged the code and found that there is problem in the base module

```
mail->static->src->js->models->messages->abstract_message.js -> isNote()
```

function is returning NULL!
Please tell me is it a bug or how to differentiate between message and note.

Thank you!

[Screen Shot - 1(Odoo 12)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al0qK.png)
[Screen Shot - 2 (Odoo 11)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohEc6.png)

Comment: What do you mean by the "notification section"?

Comment: Where you get all log details like messages, logged notes and scheduled activities in sales_orders - > quotations at the very bottom or in the right side panel (for large screen displays.)

Comment: You probably need to supply some screenshot(s) to let us understand what you are missing.

Comment: I have attached SS in my Question please check it out...

Comment: Seems to be removed, Odoo 13 isn't showing it, too.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve it?
I want to categorize Note section and separate Notifications section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can differentiate notes from messages by the background color of the notification:

[image]

---

To distinguish a note in code, you have to use [the `internal` field of the message's `subtype_id`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/838cb0e8c10de4229c8b04592aefa1808771bbb3/addons/mail/models/mail_message_subtype.py#L26-L28):

```
is_note = message.subtype_id.internal
```

Comment: Even I had thought about the same solution but don't know how to do it!

Comment: I added a screenshot to the answer, so you understand it better.

Comment: Hey @Yajo thanq man for your reply but I was asking from code point of view. Can u help me with that ?

Comment: Updated my answer, sorry. Try to be more specific on your questions next time ;)

Comment: Thanq so much @Yajo and noted that ;)